How to calculate linear momentum from angular momentum? (Newtonian)
None of the mechanics textbooks I own directly provide a method to calculate linear momentum from angular momentum.
If there is a way, it would be worth knowing, and have consequences worth discussing.
But, based on Eq.\eqref{e94} found in Landau and Lifshitz "Mechanics", through valid math steps, I derive:
$$ P_x = ( L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) - L_z(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta;  \tag{1}\label{PxLz0}$$
$$ P_y = ( L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) - L_x(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta;  \tag{2}\label{PyLx0}$$
$$ P_z = ( L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) - L_y(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta;  \tag{3}\label{PzLy0}$$
and also:
$$ P_x = ( L_y(\vec{O}) - L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) ) / \Delta;  \tag{4}\label{PxLy0}$$
$$ P_y = ( L_z(\vec{O}) - L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) ) / \Delta;  \tag{5}\label{PyLz0}$$
$$ P_z = ( L_x(\vec{O}) - L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) ) / \Delta;  \tag{6}\label{PzLx0}$$
where $\Delta$ is any physical distance in meters.
So, it appears there is a method, unless I fumbled the math, or Eq.\eqref{e94} has some limitation,
or I did not account for some underlying assumption.
As a form of validation, I applied these equations to randomly generated groups of particles, and
they always provided the correct linear momentum values.
Being unaffiliated with a university, I have very limited means to check if (and where) methods to
accomplish this may be published.
What is the standard method to calculate linear momentum from spatially separated values of angular momentum?
If no standard method exists, is this method valid?
If this method is not valid, is it not possible?
Derivation below:

Using only these definitions (where $\vec{O}$ is an arbitrary observation point) :
$$ \vec{P}_{total} \equiv \sum_i \vec{p}_i $$
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}) \equiv \sum_i (\vec{r}_i - \vec{O}) \times \vec{p}_i; $$
in their 1960 textbook "Mechanics", Landau and Lifshitz derived (Newtonian) equation 9.4,
finding the difference between angular momentum at any two arbitrary observation points:
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\vec{\Delta})=\vec{L}( \vec{O}) - (\vec{\Delta}\times\vec{P}_{total}). \tag{LLM9.4}\label{e94}$$
Using Eq.\eqref{e94}, if we choose a $\vec{\Delta}$ parallel to the $x$, $y$, or $z$ axis,
this simplifies the resulting component equations.
Temporarily choosing $\vec{\Delta}=\Delta\hat{x}$, we find
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - (\Delta \hat{x}\times\vec{P}_{total}); \tag{7}\label{Ldx1}$$
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - \Delta (0,-P_z, P_y); \tag{8}\label{Ldx2}$$
which we can separate into
$$ L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) = L_x(\vec{O}); \tag{9}\label{Lxdx}$$
$$ L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) = L_y(\vec{O}) + \Delta P_z; \tag{10}\label{LyPz}$$
$$ L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) = L_z(\vec{O}) - \Delta P_y; \tag{11}\label{LzPy}$$
We can rearrange Eqs \eqref{LyPz} and \eqref{LzPy} to find
$$ P_y = ( L_z(\vec{O}) - L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) ) / \Delta; \tag{12}\label{PyLz2}$$
$$ P_z = ( L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{x}) - L_y(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta. \tag{13}\label{PzLy2}$$
Temporarily choosing $\vec{\Delta}=\Delta\hat{y}$, we find
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - (\Delta \hat{y}\times\vec{P}_{total}); \tag{14}\label{Ldy1}$$
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - \Delta (P_z, 0, - P_x); \tag{15}\label{Ldy2}$$
which we can separate into
$$ L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) = L_x(\vec{O}) - \Delta P_z; \tag{16}\label{LxPz}$$
$$ L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) = L_y(\vec{O}); \tag{17}\label{Lydy}$$
$$ L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) = L_z(\vec{O}) + \Delta P_x; \tag{18}\label{LzPx}$$
We can rearrange Eqs \eqref{LxPz} and \eqref{LzPx} to find
$$ P_z = ( L_x(\vec{O}) - L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) ) / \Delta; \tag{19}\label{PzLx1}$$
$$ P_x = ( L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) - L_z(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta. \tag{20}\label{PxLz1}$$
Temporarily choosing $\vec{\Delta}=\Delta\hat{z}$, we find
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - (\Delta \hat{z}\times\vec{P}_{total}); \tag{21}\label{Ldz1}$$
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - \Delta (- P_y, P_x, 0 ); \tag{22}\label{Ldz2}$$
which we can separate into
$$ L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) = L_x(\vec{O}) + \Delta P_y; \tag{23}\label{LxPy}$$
$$ L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) = L_y(\vec{O}) - \Delta P_x; \tag{24}\label{LyPx}$$
$$ L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) = L_z(\vec{O}); \tag{25}\label{Lzdz}$$
We can rearrange Eqs \eqref{LyPx} and \eqref{LxPy} to find
$$ P_x = ( L_y(\vec{O}) - L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) ) / \Delta; \tag{26}\label{PxLy1}$$
$$ P_y = ( L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) - L_x(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta. \tag{27}\label{PyLx1}$$

so is $(0,1,0)m$ just $\hat y$?

JEB, yes, 1 meter in the positive y direction. The meter is important go between linear and angular units.

well if you just use $\hat y$, it would be a lot easier to read, but it not, at least put the $m$ in ${\rm m}$ font (backslash rm).

This is such profoundly ugly notation for no reason.

well if you want any traction, you have to fix the notation. So, my earlier comment, and writing $p_x = L/1m$ is just weird, sub in $|\hat x|$ for $1m$. Also some explanation of the idea.. it looks like your shifting the origin an a direction to extract the linear momentum in that direction from the total angular momentum?

also, labeling the particle with a latin $i$ index is messy. Ppl interested in this will be comfortable with the convention: $L_i = \espilon_{ijk}p_jp_k$ where the indices run over $(x, y, z)$ or $(1, 2,3)$...depending on taste. You should make it $n \in [1, N]$. Clarity counts for a lot. I have $N \gg 1$ comments and answer on this site exploring posters to use clear notation--it not only helps the answers, it helps the OP get a clearer understanding of the problem.

@JEB I admit to being untutored in elegant PhysicsSE notation. I did skim some of the help. It is unlikely I will become a regular contributor, but I will try to do better. What document should I use to guide me? And am I allowed to edit for notation at this late date?

@hft Why did you remove the link to my youTube video?

Because this is not a place where you publicize your bullshit youtube videos. If you have a question, ask a question. If you have a video you want to publicize, go away.

@hft The rule I saw said that , if I was to reference a video, I should include enough context in the post that readers would not need to follow the link. So, is this your personal opinion? Or, where is the actual rule posted?

The video does not provide any additional relevant context. All you said is that you want to make sure your equations are correct for some video you made. How is the video providing additional relevant context?

@hft Again, is there an existing rule I violated, or are you just meddling?

@hft, I read some posts about people referencing their own papers. I think that this is in that direction. If you don't have some rule or persuasive argument, I will roll back your edit. You are free to try to find a flaw in my equations, or ignore my post altogether.

See how not to be a spammer for guidelines on when linking your own stuff is acceptable. In this case the link to the video does not add any evident value to this question, so it should not be included. Attempts to promote your own Youtube content by asking questions about it will be viewed as spam and may lead to suspension.

Angular momentum around a isolated traveling particle forms a "tunnel" pattern, around the particle path,
conserved over infinite time and distance. If we could visually see the angular momentum vectors, the
pattern would make the particle-path obvious, even if the particle was not visible, far down the path.
image
angular momentum of single particle
Crucially, the rate that the angular momentum changes with distance from the path is proportional to the particle momentum.
The pattern indicates magnitude and direction of the linear momentum, both visually and algebraically.

Facing in direction of travel, Angular Momentum appears clockwise

A.M. rate of change is proportional to momentum

higher momentum and proportionally higher rate of change
In their 1960 textbook "Mechanics", Landau and Lifshitz derived (Newtonian) equation \eqref{e94}, finding the difference between
angular momentum at any two arbitrary observation points:
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\vec{\Delta})=\vec{L}( \vec{O}) - (\vec{\Delta}\times\vec{P}_{total})\tag{LLM9.4}\label{e94}$$
This equation was derived directly from definitions of linear and angular momentum. Eq. \eqref{e94} is true for
any group of particles in a Newtonian frame of reference, at any time $t$, regardless of forces or non-conservation.
At time $t$, we can see that the angular momentum at any point near or far from $\vec{O}$ is the current value of $\vec{L}(\vec{O})$,
plus the "tunnel" angular momentum $\vec{r}\times\vec{P}_{total}$ of an imaginary particle at position $O$, with momentum
$\vec{P}_{total}$. $(\vec{r}=-\vec{\Delta})$.

tunnel pattern with added vector constant
Counterintuitively, the "tunnels" of $n$ particles, at whatever angles, add up to one communal tunnel, plus a vector constant.
If we could see the pattern of angular momentum, it would make the direction of $P_{total}$ obvious, and shown below,
the 3D rates of change of angular momentum produce all components of $P_{total}$.
It is well known that angular momentum anywhere equals angular momentum at the center of mass, plus angular momentum of an imaginary
particle at the center of mass with $\vec{p}=\vec{P}_{total}$. "Mechanics" uses Eq. \eqref{e94} to prove this, setting $O=$ center of mass.
But the equation is true at any $(x,y,z)$ position.
Given $\vec{O}=(x_O,y_O,z_O)$, if we choose a $\vec{\Delta}$ parallel to the $x$, $y$, or $z$ axis,
this simplifies the resulting component equations.
Temporarily choosing $\vec{\Delta}=\Delta\hat{y}$, we find
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - (\Delta \hat{y}\times\vec{P}_{total})\,;\tag{1}\label{Ldy1}$$
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - \Delta (P_z, 0, - P_x)\,;\tag{2}\label{Ldy2}$$
which we can separate into
$$ L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) = L_x(\vec{O}) - \Delta P_z; \tag{3}\label{Lxyz}$$
$$ L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) = L_y(\vec{O}); \tag{4}\label{Lyy}$$
$$ L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) = L_z(\vec{O}) + \Delta P_x. \tag{5}\label{Lzyx}$$
Plotted as a function of $\Delta, L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y})$ is a straight line, with slope $-P_z$, that intercepts $y=y_O$ at $L_x(\vec{O})$.
( $L_x$ is not special, all components of $\vec{L}$ vary linearly with respect to position. )

$L_x$ plotted vs $\Delta$
We can rearrange the Eq.\eqref{Lxyz} to find the (negative) slope, calculating -rise/run from point $\vec{O}$ to point $\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}$:
$$ P_z = ( L_x(\vec{O}) - L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) ) / \Delta. \tag{6}\label{Pzdy}$$
If we choose $\Delta=1$ (meter)
$$ P_z = ( L_x(\vec{O}) - L_x(\vec{O}+\hat{y}\mathrm{m}) ) / 1\mathrm{m}. \tag{7}\label{Pz1y}$$
We can do the same for $P_x$ in Eq.\eqref{Lzyx}:
$$ P_x = ( L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{y}) - L_z(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta; \tag{8}\label{Pxdy}$$
$$ P_x = ( L_z(\vec{O}+\hat{y}\mathrm{m}) - L_z(\vec{O}) ) / 1\mathrm{m}. \tag{9}\label{Px1y}$$
A displacement parallel to the $y$ axis yields components ($P_x$ and $P_z$) perpendicular to the y axis, but it does not
provide any information about $P_y$. To get the missing $P_y$ component, we need a displacement perpendicular to $y$.
Temporarily choosing a displacement parallel to the $z$ axis yields components ($P_x$ and $P_y$) perpendicular to the z axis:
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - (\Delta \hat{z}\times\vec{P}_{total})\,;\tag{10}\label{Ldz1}$$
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z})=\vec{L}(\vec{O}) - \Delta (- P_y, P_x, 0)\,;\tag{11}\label{Ldz2}$$
separating dimensions:
$$ L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) = L_x(\vec{O}) + \Delta P_y; \tag{12}\label{Lxzy}$$
$$ L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) = L_y(\vec{O}) - \Delta P_x; \tag{13}\label{Lyzx}$$
$$ L_z(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) = L_z(\vec{O}) \tag{14}\label{Lzz}; $$
solving for components:
$$ P_y = ( L_x(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) - L_x(\vec{O}) ) / \Delta; \tag{15}\label{Pydz}$$
$$ P_x = ( L_y(\vec{O}) - L_y(\vec{O}+\Delta\hat{z}) ) / \Delta; \tag{16}\label{Pxdz}$$
setting $\Delta=1$ (meter):
$$ P_y = ( L_x(\vec{O}+\hat{z}\mathrm{m}) - L_x(\vec{O}) ) / 1\mathrm{m}; \tag{17}\label{Py1z}$$
$$ P_x = ( L_y(\vec{O}) - L_y(\vec{O}+\hat{z}\mathrm{m}) ) / 1\mathrm{m}. \tag{18}\label{Px1z}$$
Derived from Eq. \eqref{e94}, Equations 1 - 18 are always true, at any $(x,y,z,t)$.
We could also derive components from $\vec{\Delta}=\Delta\hat{x}$, but we already have ($P_x$, $P_y$, and $P_z$)
from Eqs. \eqref{Px1y}, \eqref{Py1z}, and \eqref{Pz1y} , so:
$$ \vec{P} = ( (L_z(\vec{O}+\hat{y}\mathrm{m}) - L_z(\vec{O})/ 1\mathrm{m},( L_x(\vec{O}+\hat{z}\mathrm{m}) - L_x(\vec{O} ) / 1\mathrm{m},(L_x(\vec{O}) - L_x(\vec{O}+\hat{y}\mathrm{m})) / 1\mathrm{m}\tag{19}\label{P1m}. $$
Linear Momentum $\vec{P}$ is always calculable from $\vec{L}$ at three non-linear points, like $O$, $O+\hat{y}$, and $O+\hat{z}$.
Being derived from Landau and Lifshitz "Mechanics" Eq.\eqref{e94}, I believe this "established" enough to be discuss-able on PhysicsSE.
Having often verified numerically, and seeing no counter-examples, this all seems solid.
I am unaware of any publication deriving linear momentum from angular momentum.
If no one provides reference to such a publication in the comments, I will ask that as a separate question.

To cut to the chase: the answer is that no, your equation is not correct.
To justify this answer, let me first rephrase what I think you're trying to do in different notation, that I find clearer.
You start from the definition of angular momentum. Let's just say there is one particle for simplicity. The angular momentum about the origin is
$$
\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}
$$
Now you shift your origin by $-\vec{\Delta}$, and compute the angular momentum about this new origin. This leads to angular momentum $\vec{L}'$, given by
$$
\vec{L}' = (\vec{r} + \vec{\Delta}) \times \vec{p}
$$
Subtracting $\vec{L}'$ and $\vec{L}$ gives
$$
\vec{L}' - \vec{L} = \vec{\Delta} \times \vec{p}
$$
and now what you would like to do is solve this equation for $\vec{p}$.
You cannot do this, without knowing additional information. Specifically, you need to know the component of $\vec{p}$ along $\vec{\Delta}$, explicitly: $p_\Delta = \frac{\vec{\Delta} \cdot{p}}{|\vec{\Delta}|}$. The reason is that $\vec{\Delta} \times k\vec{\Delta} = 0$ for any constant $k$. This means that the above vector equation really only has two independent conditions, but you need three to fully solve for the three components of $\vec{p}$. So you have two equations in three unknowns, and therefore you cannot solve for all of the unknowns.
In your write-up, you have taken $\vec{\Delta} = \Delta \hat{y}$, where $\hat{y}$ is a unit vector in the $y$ direction, and you chose $\Delta= 1\ {\rm m}$. Then, my claim is that there is no way to solve your equation for $p_y$ (the component of $\vec{p}$ along $\vec{\Delta}$).
Indeed, looking at your writeup, you have a line:
$$ P_y = (L_x(\vec{O} + (0, 0, 1) \mathrm{m}) - L_x(\vec{O}))/1 \mathrm{m} ~ (\mathrm{symmetry}) $$
In my notation, that would be
$$
p_y = \frac{L'_x - L_x}{\Delta} \ \ {\rm by\ symmetry}
$$
The phrase "symmetry" indicates to me that you know you did not obtain this by solving an equation. You seem to be invoking symmetry to argue that $p_y$ should have a similar expression as $p_x$ and $p_z$. However, there's no reason for that to be the case. You can add any constant to $p_y$, and the vector $\vec{p}$ will still satisfy the underlying equation you were trying to solve, $\vec{L}'-\vec{L} = \vec{\Delta}\times\vec{p}$.
You can also see this from your line
$$ \vec{L}(\vec{O} + (0,1,0) \mathrm{m})-\vec{L}(\vec{O}) = - (P_z,0,-P_x) \mathrm{m} $$
which I would write as
$$
\vec{L}' - \vec{L} = \Delta \vec{p} \times \hat{y}
$$
or in components
\begin{eqnarray}
L'_x - L_x &=& - \Delta p_z \\
L'_y - L_y &=& 0 \\
L'_z - L_z &=& \Delta p_x \\
\end{eqnarray}
You can see that $p_y$ doesn't appear in these equations (either in my notation or your notation), so you cannot solve for it.

Having said all that, your basic idea that if you know the angular momentum of a particle relative to two different origins, you can reconstruct the momentum, is correct (provided the particle and the two origins are not collinear).
You can solve $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times{\vec{p}}$ for two components of $\vec{p}$. Then, assuming $\vec{\Delta}$ does not point in the same direction as $\vec{r}$, you can solve $\vec{L}' = (\vec{r}+\vec{\Delta})\times \vec{p}$ for the other component.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It's better to try to coordinate free physics when dealing with a would-be fundamental relation. As we all know: physics doesn't care about our coordinates, so we should not need them.
The idea presented appears to be this:
Given the angular momentum defined in two coordinate systems, we should be able to recover the linear momentum along projected along the vector shift along the coordinate shift (kind has parallel axis theorem energy--but I'll get back to that).
Before starting, it's important to get the differences between an affine point an a vector (without getting all mathy).
When you have a point ($a$) in a space ($E^3$), it is a physical point and doesn't care about our coordinates, but we need coordinates to describe it. To do that, we define an arbitrary origin:
$$ O_i \equiv (0, 0, 0) $$
we can the give the affine point coordinates:
$$ a_i = (a_x, a_y, a_z) $$
This is not a vector, it's an affine point, and only has meaning if it is considered with respect to the origin. Any formula that uses $a_i$ does not yield a fundamental quantity, since it tied to the origin definition (which we made up).
So if I have a mass $m$ at $a_i$ with momentum $p_i$, it has angular momentum:
$$ L_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a_jp_k $$
which is defined with respect to $O_i$ via:
$$ r_i = a_i - O_i $$
$r_i$ is a vector.
The angular momentum is not a vector. There is some inconstancy in nomenclature, but here's deal:

It's a axial-vector (which means it rotates like a vector, but is even in parity reflection)

It's pseudo-vector, which means it depends on the origin (though in particle physics (1) and (2) are used interchangeably to mean (1).


Now if I have two affine points, the difference:
$$ a_i -a'_i = (O_i + r_i) - (O_i + r'_i) = r_i - r'_r \equiv \Delta r_i $$
is an origin-independent vector
Now your premiss is: move the origin by $d_i$ (a vector translation):
$$ O'_i = O_i + d_i $$
and use angular momentum to solve for $p_id_i$ with the condition:
$$ ||d|| \equiv d_id_i = 1 $$
The two angular momentum are:
$$L_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a_jp_k $$
$$L'_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a'_jp_k $$
(now the notation is confusing because the $'$ refers now to the origin, not the vector relative to it)
Anyway, the difference in angular momentum in the two coordinates is:
$$\Delta L_i \equiv L_i - L'_i $$
$$\Delta L_i= \epsilon_{ijk}d_jp_k $$
which you want to relate to
$$ q = p_id_i $$
(I just called it $q$ so it has a name). Note that $q$ is a scalar, while $$\Delta L_i$$ is an axial vector--that's a relation that's not going to work), so you can project that on the unit vector $d_i$ to make:
$$ q_i \equiv qd_i = (p_id_i)d_i $$
That's a vector, and the relation:
$$ \Delta L_i = c q_i $$
(where $c$ is some constant) relates an axial vector to a vector. that means under parity inversion, it transform to:
$$ \Delta L_i = -c q_i $$
which means it's a parity violating relation. You just can't have that in newtonian mechanics, nor electromagnetism (unless you add axions--which is a different story).
Anyway, you should revisit your idea with notation that other people can follow, and see what happens. (Also, consider better notation for describing the same point with different origins--the way I did it was ambiguous).
Also: I used one particle for simplicity. It's a good place to start. If it works, then go multi-particle.

I used the letter $O$ to mean Observation point, not Origin. Every time I used $O$ and/or $r_i$, there was a subtraction that un-linked it from the Origin. In other words, I did not use a origin-dependent vector anywhere. So, in my post, there is no conflict with origin dependent vectors. I think changing coordinate systems would only confuse the issue.

an underlying insight (shown in the video) is that $$\partial{L}_z / \partial{y} = P_x $$ , constant throughout the entire universe. That makes it simple to subtract angular components, divide (rise/run), and get linear components.

$$ \nabla\vec{L}(x,y,z)=\nabla(\mathrm{constant}) +\nabla(z P_y - y P_z , x P_z - z P_x , yP_x -x P_y) $$

I appreciate the time you have spent on me. I know that this post must stand on its own, true or false.
If you were to watch the video, which goes over related issues, like the Landau-Lifshitz equation, deriving well known results, the Jacobian, solving by linear equations, central force, etc., you would be in a better position to understand, improve upon, and judge my post. I think.
